# Expand UITextView based on its content

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, textview, uitextview

I'm trying to expand my UITextView to change the frame based on its content.

The textView should resize its height when the text inside of it gets larger, and smaller when the user deletes the text.

I tried many answers but it didn't work.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Using the following two lines are the best answer for the question, and it solved my problem:

```
expandingTextView.textContainer.heightTracksTextView = true
expandingTextView.isScrollEnabled = false
```

**Notes:**
`expandingTextView: UITextView`.
`textContainer: NSTextContainer` is the bounds of the text inside the expandingTextView.
`heightTracksTextView: Bool` If true, the reciever will adjust its height based on the expandingTextView height.

In order to the expanding to work, you need to disable the textView scrolling by:
`isScrollEnabled = false`

Comment: Does this work for iOS 11.4? I've programmatically added a `UITextView` to the `view` of a `UIViewController`. I've tried positioning it with Auto Layout and without (just by setting its frame). In both cases, setting its `isScrollEnabled` property to `false` doesn't make its height expand as I type. What am I missing?

Comment: To get this to work, I had to set my text view's height constraint's `priority` to `.defaultLow`.

Comment: I don't see a difference caused by setting `heightTracksTextView = true`. I guess it's supposed to make the text container adjust its height when the height of its text view changes, but maybe this happens anyway, or maybe the text container height is irrelevant?

Comment: @ma11hew28 your comment literally saved me!! I think it should be highlighted!

Comment: @AlyYakan, I'm glad my comment helped you. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Under Autolayout use invalidateIntrinsicContentSize() for UITextView

```
func viewDidLoad(){
    textView.delegate = self;
    textView.isScrollEnabled = false;
}

extension Chat:UITextViewDelegate {
  func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
    textView.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize();
  }
}
```